# Cordova application build failed

Tags: cordova, cmd, build, command

i want to build my cordova application using this command `cordova build` but it's not working                                                                                 [image]

Comment: try to remove and add platform and try for build again

Comment: **it worked** ... @Naitik

Comment: Glad to help you..

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder
C:\xampp\htdocs\Cordova\Afrika\gradle\wrapper\

Rename file:
gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip